# How to delete rest of the line after matching pattern?

Tags: unix

I have several files whose contents are like below:

```
*****;ABCD
*****;XYZ
*****;HPSD hello
*****;EFGH hi
```

After the ";"(semicolon) i want to retain the word but delete anything that comes after (hello & hi)
How do i do this ?

Comment: For this case this should suffice: `awk '{print $1}' file`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk -F\; '{ split($2,map," ");print $1FS map[1]}' file
```

Set ";" as the field delimiter and then split the second field into the array map, using space as the delimiter. Print the first field, the field separator (;) and then the first index of map.